Symfony ApiPlatform creating embedded Embedded Objects
I'm new to ApiPlatform and searched a lot for the current issue I have with it.
Symfony 7
PHP 8.3
Doctrine
ApiPlatform 3.x
I am currently developing a customer contact feature.
What I want is, how I did it always before with Symfony, to persist through the endpoint "customers" with POST methode also the address object which have a ManyToOne relation with customer object.
I saw in other resources that this is possible with ApiPlatform and I did it like it was described in the documentation but the endpoint returns an error:
"detail": "Nested documents for attribute \"address\" are not allowed. Use IRIs instead.",
"status": 400,

UPDATE: according to the suggestion of Evgeny Ruban I have added'customer:write' group to each property at Address. Now the POST is successful but it still doesn't persist the address object.
Below are my current implementations for Customer and Address entities:
Customer
--------
--------
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['customer:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['customer:write']],
)]
class Customer

{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column]
private ?int $id = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
#[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $name = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 180)]
#[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write', 'address:item:get', 'address:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
#[Assert\Email]
private ?string $email = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 20)]
#[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $phone = null;

#[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Address::class,  mappedBy: 'customer', cascade: ['persist'])]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
#[Groups(['customer:read', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\Valid]
private Collection $address;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
}

Address:
---------
----------
#[ApiResource(
description: 'Customer address.',
    operations: [
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: [
                'groups' => ['address:read', 'address:item:get'],
            ],
        ),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(),
        new Put(),
        new Patch(),
     ],
     normalizationContext: [
         'groups' => ['address:read'],
     ],
     denormalizationContext: [
         'groups' => ['address:write'],
     ],
)]

class Address
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column]
private ?int $id = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
#[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', , 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $street = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 5)]
#[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $streetnumber = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 5)]
#[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $zipcode = null;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'address')]
#[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write', 'customer:write'])]
#[Assert\Valid]
private ?Customer $customer = null;

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

using JoinColumn(nullable: false) with ?Customer $customer looks wrong

And it looks that you need to add 'customer:write' group to each property at Address

Thank you for the suggestions. Yes, nullable=false was completely wrong for the relation.
Unfortunately, address is still not persisting.

So, it is possible that you forget addAddress() method or smth like that. Anyway, it is the duplicate question

Does this answer your question? How to save a Nested Relation with Entity on API Platform

Ofcourse I have addAddress() in Customer class. My implementation is similar to your example. The address is still not saved.
